# Breaking down currency in c#

Tags: c#

i'm trying to get this program to break down a user defined amount of dollars into the fewest possible bills. i don't think my for loops are running because if i put a writeline line in them it doesn't show up when i run it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the amount of money: $");
            int totalAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            calculateNumberOfBills(totalAmount);
        }

        static void calculateNumberOfBills(int totalAmount)
        {

            int[] denominations = { 20, 10, 5, 1 };
            int[] numberOfBills = new int[4];
            for (numberOfBills[0] = 0; totalAmount < 20; numberOfBills[0]++)
            {
                totalAmount = totalAmount - 20;
            }
            for (numberOfBills[1] = 0; totalAmount < 10; numberOfBills[1]++)
            {
                totalAmount = totalAmount - 10;
            }
            for (numberOfBills[2] = 0; totalAmount < 5; numberOfBills[2]++)
            {
                totalAmount = totalAmount - 5;
            }
            for (numberOfBills[3] = 0; totalAmount <= 0; numberOfBills[3]++)
            {
                totalAmount = totalAmount - 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Number of twenties" + numberOfBills[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of tens" + numberOfBills[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of fives" + numberOfBills[2]);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of ones" + numberOfBills[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the totalAmount that you are using for your tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
for (numberOfBills[0] = 0; totalAmount >= 20; numberOfBills[0]++)
    {
        totalAmount = totalAmount - 20;
    }
    for (numberOfBills[1] = 0; totalAmount >= 10; numberOfBills[1]++)
    {
        totalAmount = totalAmount - 10;
    }
    for (numberOfBills[2] = 0; totalAmount >= 5; numberOfBills[2]++)
    {
        totalAmount = totalAmount - 5;
    }
    for (numberOfBills[3] = 0; totalAmount > 0; numberOfBills[3]++)
    {
        totalAmount = totalAmount - 1;
    }
```

Comment: ok that worked, but i had to change the last loop to <code> totalAmount >= 1; </code> thanks. can you tell me why it didn't work the other way?

Comment: wow, thinking about it now it seems obvious, guess that's what i get for programming when i'm this tired.

Answer (score 2):

This is a homework question, right?

```
        for (numberOfBills[0] = 0; totalAmount < 20; numberOfBills[0]++)
```

make it

```
        for (numberOfBills[0] = 0; totalAmount >= 20; numberOfBills[0]++)
```

and try again :)
The center piece is the condition where the loop should run.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, at this point this is "not a real question" and should most probably be tagged as homework.

Your "smaller than" comparisons should be changed to "greater than" comparisons and you're good to go with your solution. What's happening now is an integer overflow, eventually causing your first for-loop , which was infinitely looping until then to break.

There are easier ways to solve your problem, try it with a single loop and the modulo operator).

Comment: +1 For the modulo operator. It's not used far as often as it should. :-)

Answer (score 0):

in your "for" loops you have inverse condition => totalAmount < 20 means that it executes loop while totalAmount is **less** than 20 - that is the opposite of what you want.

Change it to

```
for(...;totalAmount > 20; ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a bit of less code

```
    int amt = 73;

    Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>() {{20,0},{10,0},{5,0},{1,0}};
    int[] keys =new  int[dic.Count];
    dic.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

    foreach (int i in  keys)
    {            
        if (amt >= i)
        {
            dic[i] = amt / i;
            amt = amt % i;
        }
    }
```